# Plain Old Data and `std::memcpy` alignment issues

Tags: c++, memcpy, memory-alignment

Trying to respond to [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39821244/store-arbitrary-elements-in-contiguous-memory), I've proposed a solution that use `std::memcpy()` to store generic types in a buffer of `char`s.

My doubt is about possible memory alignment issues storing POD (I know that with not-POD type, as `std::string`, is very very dangerous).

In short: there are memory alignment issues with the following program?

And if they are, it's possible to write something similar (that store POD values in a `char` buffer) that is safe? And how?

```
#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>

int main()
 {
   char  buffer[100];

   double  d1 { 1.2 };

   std::memmove( buffer + 1, & d1, sizeof(double) );

   double  d2;

   std::memmove( & d2, buffer + 1, sizeof(double) );

   std::cout << d2 << std::endl;

   return 0;
 }
```

Comment: This should work.  In general should check sizeof() less than fixed buffer, but of course a double is way less than the 100 used here.

Comment: @Gregg - Of course; I've used `100` to avoid doubts about the size of the buffer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is safe.

> `[basic.types]/2:` For any trivially copyable type `T`, if two pointers to `T` point to distinct `T` objects `obj1` and `obj2`, where
>   neither `obj1` nor `obj2` is a base-class subobject, if the underlying bytes (1.7) making up `obj1` are copied
>   into `obj2`, `obj2` shall subsequently hold the same value as `obj1`.

Since `double` is trivially copyable, your code is well-defined.

Comment: I suspect it is not: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30114397/constructing-a-trivially-copyable-object-with-memcpy

Answer (score 3):

You can copy to and from an unaligned buffer. What you can't do is cast the buffer to a double * and then operate directly on the value in memory, as a double. Often that will cause an error because of alignment issues.

Comment: "*Technically assigning random bytes to a char is undefined because of trap representations.*" Not according to the standard. [basic.types]/2 says you can use `char` or `unsigned char` for trivial copying of objects.

Comment: So that's a glitch in the standard. char is allowed a trap representation and one of the clauses must be incorrect. In fact the author nodded and the type must be unsigned char.

Comment: There's no glitch. `char` is permitted to be signed or unsigned. `signed char` may or may not have a trap representation. In order for an implementation to be in line with the standard, if `signed char` can trap, then `char` *must not be signed*. So a 2's complement signed `char` type is perfectly valid. There are other places in the standard with such a requirement, such as the UTF-8 requirements on `char` (being able to convert any UTF-8 code between `char` and `unsigned char` requires `char` not trap).

Comment: Edited to remove statement about char trapping.